# JS | Sort An array of object by property when not all properties are present

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

In the following code:

```
function by(param) {
  return function(a,b) {
    if (parseInt(a[param]) < parseInt(b[param]))
        return -1;
    if (parseInt(a[param]) > parseInt(b[param]))
        return 1;
    return 0;
  }
}

var data = [{
    dogs: 3, 
    cats: 2, 
    fish: 14
},{
    dogs: 30, 
    cats: 5
},{
    dogs: 7, 
    cats: 8, 
    fish: 1
},{
    dogs: 0, 
    cats: 8
}];

console.log(data.sort(by("fish")));
```

You can see that not all objects have all properties. What i need to do is to sort these objects in an order which first have the selected parameter values sorted by their order, and then the rest however, the output received is:

```
0: Object
cats: 2
dogs: 3
fish: 14
__proto__: Object
1: Object
cats: 5   //this shouldn't be here since it doesn't contain 'fish'
dogs: 30
__proto__: Object
2: Object
cats: 8
dogs: 7
fish: 1
__proto__: Object
3: Object
cats: 8
dogs: 0
```

now i get that there's something happens when the property is undefined, however i'm not sure as to how to deal with it.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wffNn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work: http://jsfiddle.net/wffNn/1/. I used substraction instead of if since it's faster and cleaner IMO

```
function by(param) {
    return function(a,b) {
        var vala = typeof a[param] == 'undefined' ? Infinity : parseInt(a[param]);
        var valb = typeof b[param] == 'undefined' ? Infinity : parseInt(b[param]);
        return vala-valb;
   }
}
```

You can use Infinity if you want missing properties at the end, or -Infinity if you want them at the start.

You can use vala-valb if you want increasing order or valb-vala for decreasing order.

You can mix the previous two statements to get the kind of sorting you want.

Comment: Beautiful thinking! however, though you can place it at the end or beginning of the array, the sort itself will always be in descending order

Comment: Oh got it - -Infinity to reverse the whole thing - great!

Answer (score 0):

This can be written quite idiomatically using this little helper function:

```
function cmp(x, y) { return x > y ? 1 : x < y ? -1 : 0 }
```

and then

```
function by(param) {
    return function(a, b) {
        return cmp(param in b, param in a) || cmp(a[param], b[param]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i didn't choose it since it uses one extra function which could be avoided since basically the helper function controls the sorting itself, so it's a tad harder to get. It's obviously a good solution